# Running Task scheduler on Queues Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

//Mail Verification File

```
class EmailVerification extends Mailable
{

    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $user;
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('frontend.email.activation')->with([
            'email_token' => $this->user->email_token,
        ]);
    }
}
```

//SendVerificationEmail

```
class SendVerificationEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $user;
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $email = new EmailVerification($this->user);
        Mail::to($this->user->email)->send($email);
    }
}
```

i am currently working on this simple laravel projects. I am try to make use of queues to implement the user email activation function. and it works fine when i use **php artisan queue:work** to run it. i now tried to create an task scheduler to do this every five minutes

// The code Here

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new SendVerificationEmail($user))->everyFiveMinutes();
}
```

But its returning undefined variable. Is there a mistake in the above, or is there a better way to make Queues run automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Please read: [Laravel 5.5 Documentation - Queues#dispatching-jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#dispatching-jobs)

You can't schedule this kind of job, you should dispatch it.

Comment: Yeah i actually did that  **  public function register(Request $request)
        {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
        dispatch(new SendVerificationEmail($user));
        return view('frontend.others.verification');
      }**

Comment: Basically a scheduled job can't have request-related data. This is because scheduled jobs are executed asynchronously from your application and by an external process.

On the other side, you can dispatch within your request flow in your Laravel application, so you have some `$user` to pass!

Comment: Okay Thanks.. So how best do you think i can run queues automatically or on a liveserver like heroku